# uploading a file Using Reactjs with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, upload, reactjs

I am uploading a file from my react component with html tag  . In my controller I get only the image files name , whereas when i upload without using react component i get an object like below

**React way returns image name only**

```
 render :function(){
   return(

     <form className="form-group" action="/messages" method="post">
         <hr/>
         <label>Content</label>
        <textarea type="text" name="message[content]" className="form-control"/><br/>
         <label>Provider</label><br/>
         <select name="message[provider]" id="message_provider">
             <option value="facebook">facebook</option>
             <option value="twitter">twitter</option>
             <option value="linkedin">linkedin</option>
         </select><br/>
         <label>Scheduled at</label>
         <input type="datetime-local" name="message[scheduled_at]" className="form-control"/><br/>
         <label>Image</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="file" name="message[image]" id="message_image"  value={this.state.data_uri}/><br/>
         <input type="submit" value="Create Message" className="btn btn-primary"/><br/>
         <a href="/messages">Back</a>

     </form>

   );
```

}

**Regular erb way returns object**

```
  .form-group
= f.label :image
br/
= f.file_field :image
 .actions
= f.submit :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

How can i get the   object using the react way?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try adding `encType="multipart/form-data"` (note the capitalized `T`) to your `form` component.

Comment: Thank you @BinaryMuse forgot to update here had fixed it with this.